# How to showing a function is square-integrable in Quantum mechanics

Tags: vector-spaces, quantum-mechanics

Looking the A-1 section in Cohen-Tannoudji et al Quantum mechanics Vol. 1 book I get lost in the following:

$\psi(r)=\lambda_1\psi_1(r)+\lambda_2\psi_2(r) \in F$

In order to show tha $\psi(r)$ is square-integrable, expand $|\psi(r)|^2$:
$|\psi(r)|^2=|\lambda_1|^2|\psi_1(r)|^2+|\lambda_2|^2|\psi_2(r)|^2+\lambda_1^*\lambda_2\psi_1(r)^*\psi_2(r) +\lambda_1\lambda_2^*\psi_1(r)\psi_2(r)^*$

The last two terms have the same modulus which has an upper limit (Don't understand this):

$|\lambda_1||\lambda_2|[|\psi_1(r)|^2+|\psi_2(r)|^2]$

$|\psi(r)|^2$ is therefore smaller than a function whose integral converges, since $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are square-integrable (Don't understand this too).

Can someone explain this, I'll appreciate any advice, comments and suggestions!

Comment: Remember that if $a,b\in\Bbb{C}$ then $|ab|=|a||b|\leq \frac{|a|^2+|b|^2}{2}$. Why? It's very simple, start with the obvious identity $0\leq (|a|-|b|)^2$, and expand everything out to get $0\leq |a|^2-2|a||b|+|b|^2$, and rearrange to get $|a||b|\leq \frac{|a|^2+|b|^2}{2}$. Also, what do you not understand about $\psi_1,\psi_2$ being square integrable? That's part of the hypothesis. You're trying to show that if $\psi_1,\psi_2$ are square-integrable then any linear combination is also square-integrable.

Comment: Thank you very much